# How to use function's default parameter in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, default-value, syntactic-sugar

I want to do something like this.

```
function add($num1, $num2 = 1) {
    return $num1 + $num2;
}

$bool = true; // Can be true or false

if($bool) {
    add(5, 5);
} else {
    add(5);
}
```

I was asking me, if it is possible to write this logic in one line like, without repeating the default value:

```
add(5, $bool ? 5 : USE_DEFAULT_PARAMETER);
```

Comment: No, the default value only gets used, when you _don't_ pass anything for that second parameter. You could pass `null` instead in your second case, and then _inside_ your function explicitly give that parameter the "default" value 2, if it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in a second argument, then it can't default back to the default value.

However, you could set the default to null, and replace it with 1 in the code:

```php
/**
 * @param int $num1
 * @param ?int $num2 If null or omitted, it will get the value 1
 *
 * @return int
 */
function add($num1, $num2 = null) {
    // If the default value is null, set it to the default
    $num2 = $num2 ?? 1;
    
    return $num1 + $num2;
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```php
add(5, $bool ? 5 : null);
```

Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/OAQrk

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a good practice. First even if this was possible, you do not have the variable `$bool` always defined. You might want to use the function somewhere, where `$bool` does not exist. The correct way would be to use the default parameter in the return statement:

```
function add (int $num1, ?int $num2 = null): int
{
    return $num1 + ($num2 ?? DEFAULT_PARAMETER);
}
```

and when you want to call this function, you do this:

```
$number1 = 5;
$number2 = 5;

$addDefaultValue = true;

$returnedValue = add($number1, !$addDefaultValue ? $number2 : null);
```

Comment: _"First even if this was possible, you do not have the variable $bool always defined."_ - That was a strange comment. It was obviously an example, and in no way different from `$addDefaultValue` you're using. You just changed the name of the variable and reversed the comparison (which is opposite from what the OP is asking for)

Comment: I guess you misinterpreted my second code block as function declaration. This should be the function call.